# Error when trying to run command (npm run server)

Tags: angular, server-side, server-side-rendering, angular7, angular-seo

After executing npm run build:prod everything seems ok. After that, I just run npm run server as documentation explains but when I tried access localhost I get an error (ERROR [Error]) without any description and browser loading never ends.

[image: error message - image preview]

```
Angular version: 7.0.1

Angular CLI: 7.0.3
Node: 8.11.3

MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Others:

 "@angular/animations": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.2",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.4.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.2.0",
    "@netbasal/content-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.3.5",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^1.1.34",
    "@ngui/map": "^0.30.3",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@ngx-share/button": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.11",
    "angular-feather": "^5.3.0",
    "angular2-cookie-law": "^6.0.4",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "~2.8.4",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "^3.7.3",
    "intl-tel-input": "^14.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-scroll-to-el": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-smart-modal": "^6.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "symbol-observable": "^1.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "4.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

Comment: Post your package.json fully

Comment: @sankar

Thank you.
My package.json

https://imgur.com/M0h08zz